# C# Tic Tac Toe Efficiency

Tags: c#

I've made a tic tac toe in C# but I've hardcoded some lines so I was wondering if there were more efficient ways of doing things.

So first off, I have an array of PictureBoxes

```
PictureBox[] picBoxes = new PictureBox[NUM_OF_SPACES];
```

and it's initialized with my pictures

```
picBoxes = new PictureBox[] { picBox0, picBox1, picBox2, picBox3, picBox4, picBox5, picBox6, picBox7, picBox8 };
```

I was wondering if there was a better way of checking who won using my array of pictureboxes because currently I have

```
if(picBox0.Tag == "X" && picBox1.Tag == "X" && picBox2.Tag == "X")
        {
            gameOver = true;
            finalMessage = "X is the winner";
        }
```

8 times for X and another 8 for O.  So what I was wondering is if there's a better way to check who won using arrays, like comparing the picBox[] to an array of winners or something.

Answer (score 5):

Keep your game logic/board representation and board rendering separate. This will allow you to extend your game much more easily e.g. if you want to add AI. One way would be to store your board as an int or pair of ints (you can bitmask but it is probably easier to have one for each player). You can then AND these integers with known winning positions.

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, as Ananke said keep your game logic out of your presentation logic.

For completion you could use bit boards (sorry can't help it, the chess developer in me). There are different approaches to this, one is to have two bit boards, one for each player, another is to have a combined bitboard for the two players.

For simplicity though I will suggest having two bitboards.

Since it is tic-tac-toe on a 3-by-3 board 9 bits should be sufficient, so you could achieve this with a regular `int` (again keeping it simple). Each field on the board is represented by a bit in the integer field number 1 is the first bit (least significant bit), field number two, the next and so on. The board would be represented as follows:

```
Field number:    Field 1   | Field 2   | Field 3
Mask for field:  000000001 | 000000010 | 000000100
                 ----------+-----------+----------
Field number:    Field 4   | Field 5   | Field 6
Mask for field:  000001000 | 000010000 | 000100000
                 ----------+-----------+----------
Field number:    Field 7   | Field 8   | Field 9
Mask for field:  001000000 | 010000000 | 100000000
```

Now consider a game where the situation on the board looks like the following:

```
X | O | X
X | O | 
X |   | O
```

The two bit boards would look like the following, for player 1 (X) it would look like this: `001001101` and for player 2 (O) it would look like this: `100010010`. To check for a winner we simply check the two bit patterns for the winning condition patterns:

```
X | X | X     |   |       |   |     X |   |       | X |       |   | X
  |   |     X | X | X     |   |     X |   |       | X |       |   | X
  |   |       |   |     X | X | X   X |   |       | X |       |   | X
    0x003       0x038       0x1C0       0x049       0x092       0x124
000000111   000111000   111000000   001001001   010010010   100100100

X |   |       |   | X
  | X |       | X |  
  |   | X   X |   |  
    0x111       0x054
100010001   001010100
```

What is done is that for each player we iterate over the winning conditions, and check whether any of them are met. A check could look like this:

```
if ((boardPlayer1 & winCondition1) == winCondition1) {
    // Player 1 has won, using winCondition1
}
else if ((boardPlayer2 & winCondition1) == winCondition1) {
    // Player 2 has won, using winCondition1
}
```

The win conditions should probably be in an array so you can loop through them instead of checking them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multidimensional or jagged arrays for this and iterate through items line by line
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

```
var boxes = new YourObject[3,3];
```

or

```
var boxes = new YourObject[3][3];
```

Comment: And what about diagonal winners?