# Is there a better way to detect combinations of values in arrays than a bunch of if/else statements?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm working on a project for my class where I have to make a tic-tac-toe game, so I need to be able to detect the combinations that would let you win. Right now I'm just using many many if statements (one else that keeps you playing if there wasn't a win) to detect all the combinations in the array of Xs and Os. It looks... frankly disgusting lmao. Is there a better/faster way to do this?

The code (now in text form (sorry I didn't know the standards)):

```
bool win = false;
        while (win == false)
        {
            //diagonal left to right
            if (array[0, 0] == "X" && array[1, 1] == "X" && array[2, 2] == "X")
            {
                win = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Player one wins!");
                EndScreen("Player One");
            }
            //diagonal right to left
            if (array[0, 2] == "X" && array[1, 1] == "X" && array[2, 0] == "X")
            {
                win = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Player one wins!");
                EndScreen("Player One");
            }
            //vertical left
            if (array[0, 0] == "X" && array[1, 0] == "X" && array[2, 0] == "X")
            {
                win = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Player one wins!");
                EndScreen("Player One");
            }
            //vertical middle
            if (array[0, 1] == "X" && array[1, 1] == "X" && array[2, 1] == "X")
            {
                win = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Player one wins!");
                EndScreen("Player One");
            }
            //vertical right
            if (array[0, 2] == "X" && array[1, 2] == "X" && array[2, 2] == "X")
            {
                win = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Player one wins!");
                EndScreen("Player One");
            }
            //horizontal top
            if (array[0, 0] == "X" && array[0, 1] == "X" && array[0, 2] == "X")
            {
                win = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Player one wins!");
                EndScreen("Player One");
            }
            //horizontal middle
            if (array[1, 0] == "X" && array[1, 1] == "X" && array[1, 2] == "X")
            {
                win = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Player one wins!");
                EndScreen("Player One");
            }
            //horizontal bottom
            if (array[2, 0] == "X" && array[2, 1] == "X" && array[2, 2] == "X")
            {
                win = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Player one wins!");
                EndScreen("Player One");
            }
        }
```

its horrendous please tell me there's a better/easier option

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any code in your question. Are you able to edit your question to show what you've done?

Comment: If *"[this is what the code looks like]"* is going to be a screenshot, stop. Post all code as text as required by the community standards.

Comment: It would help to see the code you're asking about. Assuming your board is a 2d array it's not difficult to use a loop and an array of offsets to scan each line of squares and see if they all match one symbol.

Comment: The code should show up in the picture now! Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: See duplicate. Personally, while not mentioned in the duplicate's answers, I like the observation that each cell of the board can be represented with 2 bits, for a total of 18 bits to represent every possible board configuration. That's in theory 262,144 possible values, but of course you only care about the winning configurations, which is a _much_ smaller set. You could easily load up a `HashSet<int>` with those values, and just translate the current board state to an `int` and see if it's in the set.

Comment: Looks like you didn't read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67204181/is-there-a-better-way-to-detect-combinations-of-values-in-arrays-than-a-bunch-of?noredirect=1#comment118789156_67204181) from @madreflection

Comment: Ah, and related to my comment about hash set, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33039151) in the second duplicate target, which applies a similar approach (not quite the same, but either way would work fine).

Comment: Thank you so much! I will go learn about hash sets now :)

Comment: This works in your situation: `bool x_wins = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).SelectMany(i => new Func<int, string>[] { x => array[i, x], x => array[x, i] }).Concat(new Func<int, string>[] { x => array[x, x], x => array[2 - x, x], }).Where(f => String.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => f(x))) == "XXX").Any();`.